# Customizing a chartjs tooltip to only show the Y value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is there a way to customize the chartjs tooltip to show only the Y Value without overriding all the callbacks?

Reading through [the documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html) it seems like all of the callbacks would have to be overridden to return an empty string, except for one of the callbacks which would return the value only.

So for example in [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4fuc2m?file=index.ts) the bar value tooltip for the year 2010 show should only `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two options to override the default tooltip: `external` and `callbacks`. Using the `external` option is inherently overcomplicated for simply removing some components within the tooltip. The simpler approach is still overriding the callbacks.

However, you don't need to override all the callbacks, as most of them [defaults to do nothing](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/bfce645fd35a14c83e55d7545e4e486ad156b3db/src/plugins/plugin.tooltip.js#L356). You only need to override `title` and `label`, and set `displayColors` to `false` if you don't want the color box to be shown:

```js
options: {
    plugins: {
        tooltip:{
            enabled: true,
            displayColors: false,
            callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItem){
                    return '';
                },
                label: function(tooltipItem){
                    return tooltipItem.formattedValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```